# How to pass file from JavaScript to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is it possible to pass file from JavaScript to PHP? (Best using ajax).If we have following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <body>

   <input type='file' id='upld' onChange=' f=this.files[0] '> 
   <input type='button' onClick='ajax_pass()'>

     <script>

      function ajax_pass()
      {

       console.log(f);

        //Send 'f' using ajax to php imaginary file...
      }

     </script>

  </body>

 </html>
```

I'm new to JS programming and can't imagine how POST or GET can contain whole image.Can you clarify it to me please?

Comment: You can try to use a library like http://fineuploader.com/

Comment: only possible way is Ajax.

Comment: this does the job : https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/uploading-file-using-xmlhttprequest-level-2/

Answer (score 7):

**HTML Code**

```
<input id="myfile" type="file" name="myfile" />
<button id="upload" value="Upload" />
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).on("click", "#upload", function() {
    var file_data = $("#myfile").prop("files")[0];   // Getting the properties of file from file field
    var form_data = new FormData();                  // Creating object of FormData class
    form_data.append("file", file_data)              // Appending parameter named file with properties of file_field to form_data
    form_data.append("user_id", 123)                 // Adding extra parameters to form_data
    $.ajax({
                url: "/upload_file.php",
                dataType: 'script',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         // Setting the data attribute of ajax with file_data
                type: 'post'
       });
});
```

**Php Code**

```
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST);
```