# How to pass file input from HTML to PHP in OctoberCMS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, octobercms

Here is a demonstration of the issue:

**HTML**

```
<form data-request="onSubmit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
function onSubmit()
{
    echo $_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"];
}
```

This code always outputs

> "Undefined index: fileUpload"

Which clearly means that PHP isn't able to access the data since the index that should contain a file is undefined. How would I be able to pass a file input by the client into PHP?

Solutions can use javascript with jQuery if necessary.

P.S. I already tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971231/how-to-pass-file-from-javascript-to-php). It did not work.

Comment: looks like something very specific to your CMS

Comment: No `action` attribute appears at `<form>` element. Where is `form` submitted to?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't know what you mean but when you press the submit button it executes the PHP onSubmit function that's how I know that `$_FILES["fileUpload"]["name"];` is undefined. Could that be because it's only executing the function, not actually passing the data into PHP? Yes, that's why I asked this question.

@nogad yes, I know, that's why I specified it in the title and tag

Comment: @MarkKramer what is the output of var_dump($_FILES)

Comment: It generates an Alert that contains `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>G:\Wamp\www\October Dev\storage\cms\cache\12\55\test-page-2.htm.php:6:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
 <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>[]`

Comment: Do you want to use Ajax or that would be find for page to refresh?

Comment: Honestly I'm just going to look into using a CMS that has the capability to use php normally. Unfortunately I can't find any that I like anywhere near as much as October. They're all so much less intuitive. (except where it comes to PHP)

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot better idea to use the built in helper classes to access the post data.
Use this in you handler function to access the uploaded file:

```
Input::file('fileUpload');
```

Comment: I tried this thoroughly and determined it doesn't work. Similar functions like  `Input::get` will work but `Input::file` is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files through AJAX is fairly complicated, I recommend that you utilize the [frontend file upload plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/netsti-uploader) (or check out [the code it's based on](https://github.com/responsiv/uploader-plugin) and implement it yourself) to handle that.

See [octobercms/october#2428](https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2428), [octobercms/october#2627](https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2627), and https://octobercms.com/forum/post/frontend-file-upload for more information on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you just changed `data-request="onSubmit"` to `action="someURL.php"` the form should work just fine.